# where is 'render_template' coming from in Soundcloud's api code?

Tags: python, api, soundcloud

Let me break this down for you. Im working with Django 1.4 (so, obviously with Python too, which would be v2.7.1). In SoundClouds Developer docs, its says you can embed the player with the following code - given that you've registered your app & downloaded the SDK (which I've done):

```
import soundcloud

# create a client object with your app credentials
client = soundcloud.Client(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID')

# get a tracks oembed data
track_url = 'http://soundcloud.com/forss/flickermood'
embed_info = client.get('/oembed', url=track_url)

# render the html for the player widget
return render_template('player.html', widget=embed_info['html'])
```

So my question is where this render_template coming from? I get an error in Django saying render_template is not defined. Is that the same as the render_to_response in django? I'm not sure what's what here. Thanks.

[EDIT] The SoundClouds developers documentation: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#playing

Comment: You should link to the SoundClouds developer docs so we can help you figure this out.

Comment: But of course. How negligent of me.

Comment: I found it as well googling for some of the code.  The example looks broken to me.  render_template is nowhere to be found, and looks like something from ruby instead.  I would report it to soundcloud.

Comment: See your question was answered. Thanks for the feedback -- I've updated the SoundCloud developer docs to remove assumptions about frameworks. The player widget code samples now just print out the widget html.

Comment: Just for future reference, I had to access the html code with "embed_info.obj['html']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking it through, I assume render_template is just a placeholder call to whatever your favorite rendering tool is.

I assume embed_info['html'] contains the full HTML code to embed the widget in your page, so try printing it and see if it looks right.  Then pick whatever templating language you want, and pass this variable to it as a widget to embed.

Comment: what does print embed_info say ? What does print dir(embed_info) say ?

Comment: Well... dir() gives a bunch of methods, obviously... but it seems the html code is in a dict within the obj method/attribute. So... i guess it's a matter of gaining access to it. ...if that makes sense.

Comment: within the obj method/attribute ? Not sure what that means.  What does print type(embed_info) say?

Comment: well when I type dir(embed_info), it returns this: ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'error', 'fields', 'keys', 'obj', 'raw_data', 'status_code', 'url'].

So within 'obj' is a dict that has all the html info in it.

Comment: still interested in what the type is.  You've seen the html in the dict ?

Comment: type(embed_info) is <class 'soundcloud.resource.Resource'>. Yeah, I've seen the html in the dict ...And its beautiful! :P But yeah, you were right: render_template is just a placeholder.